# I am getting errors with the Flutter News Toolkit

Tags: flutter

I was creating a project and when I run the development I get error

> The argument type 'void Function(String?, Map<String, String>, Element?, dynamic)' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'void Function(String?, Map<String, String>, Element?)?'.dartargument_type_not_assignable,

and I cannot seem to fix it no matter what I do the html.dart file looks like this

```
import 'package:app_ui/app_ui.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter_html/flutter_html.dart' as flutter_html;

import 'package:news_blocks/news_blocks.dart';
import 'package:url_launcher/url_launcher.dart';

/// {@template html}
/// A reusable html news block widget.
/// {@endtemplate}
class Html extends StatelessWidget {
  /// {@macro html}
  const Html({required this.block, super.key});

  /// The associated [HtmlBlock] instance.
  final HtmlBlock block;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final theme = Theme.of(context);
    return Padding(
      padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: AppSpacing.sm),
      child: flutter_html.Html(
        onLinkTap: (url, context, attributes, element) {
          if (url == null) return;
          final uri = Uri.tryParse(url);
          if (uri == null) return;
          launchUrl(uri).ignore();
        },
        data: block.content,
        style: {
          'p': flutter_html.Style.fromTextStyle(
            theme.textTheme.bodyLarge!,
          ),
          'h1': flutter_html.Style.fromTextStyle(
            theme.textTheme.displayLarge!,
          ),
          'h2': flutter_html.Style.fromTextStyle(
            theme.textTheme.displayMedium!,
          ),
          'h3': flutter_html.Style.fromTextStyle(
            theme.textTheme.displaySmall!,
          ),
          'h4': flutter_html.Style.fromTextStyle(
            theme.textTheme.headlineMedium!,
          ),
          'h5': flutter_html.Style.fromTextStyle(
            theme.textTheme.headlineSmall!,
          ),
          'h6': flutter_html.Style.fromTextStyle(
            theme.textTheme.titleLarge!,
          ),
        },
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

I had a same problem, and I solved this as the [official example](https://github.com/flutter/news_toolkit/blob/main/flutter_news_example/packages/news_blocks_ui/lib/src/html.dart).

1. Remove 'context' parameter

```
    onLinkTap: (url, attributes, element) {
        if (url == null) return;
        final uri = Uri.tryParse(url);
        if (uri == null) return;
        launchUrl(uri).ignore();
    },
```

2. Update flutter_html: ^3.0.0-alpha.6 on packages/news_blocks_ui/pubspec.yaml

```
    flutter_html: ^3.0.0-beta.2
```

Then,

```
flutter pub clean
flutter pub get
```

I hope this also worked for your case.